# Transact-SQL Select Query Giving duplicate values

Tags: sql, t-sql

first off, thank you for taking the time to look at this.

I am trying to collect data from 3 tables and make a reference chart that allows the end user to see the stored data.

Basically I have 3 tables for this example:
USERS:

```
USER_PK USER_ID USER_NAME
1   10000       Bob
2   10001       Sally
3   10003       Joe
4   10004       Susan
```

SKILL_TYPE:

```
SKILL_PK    SKILL_NAME
11  Point of Sale
22  Digital Sales
33  Customer Service
44  Specialist Support
```

SKILL_ASSOCIATION:

```
SKILL_ASSOC_PK  SKILL_PK    USER_PK START_DATE  STOP_DATE   Priority
99  11  1   36526   500000  2
88  11  2   36527   500000  3
77  22  1   36526   500000  3
66  33  3   36528   500000  1
55  44  4   36525   500000  1
444 33  4   36525   500000  4
```

(I know I've probably broken some rules with cataloging this data I did it in SQL Express, however it is only an example and not representative of the real data I am using)

My Select Query Returns an unwanted result with multiple lines for each USER:
Statement:

```
 SELECT USERS.[USER_NAME], USERS.[USER_ID], 
    (CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME ='Point of Sale' Then  SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS 'POS', 

    (CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME ='Digital Sales' Then  SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS 'DS',
    (CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME ='Customer Service' Then  SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS 'CS',
    (CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME ='Specialist Support' Then  SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS 'Spec'
    FROM USERS
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SKILL_ASSOCIATION] AS SA ON SA.USER_PK = USERS.USER_PK
    INNER JOIN SKILL_TYPE AS ST ON ST.SKILL_PK = SA.SKILL_PK
```

Result:

```
USER_NAME   USER_ID POS DS  CS  Spec
Bob 10000       2   NULL    NULL    NULL
Sally   10001       3   NULL    NULL    NULL
Bob 10000       NULL    3   NULL    NULL
Joe 10003       NULL    NULL    1   NULL
Susan   10004       NULL    NULL    NULL    1
Susan   10004       NULL    NULL    4   NULL
```

I've tried using distinct as well with similar results.
Desired Results:

```
NAME    ID  POS DS  CS  Spec
Bob     1   2   3       
Sally   2   3           
Joe                 1
Susan               4   1
```

I have very limited Query access with this SQL Server and cannot create/modify or delete from it to accomplish my objective.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Thank you Yogesh Sharma! Couldn't quite figure out the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output implies that an aggregation by user along with taking the `MAX` of each of the `CASE` expressions should work:

```
SELECT
    u.[USER_NAME],
    u.[USER_ID], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME = 'Point of Sale' THEN SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS POS, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME = 'Digital Sales' THEN SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS DS,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME = 'Customer Service' THEN SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS CS,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ST.SKILL_NAME = 'Specialist Support' THEN SA.[PRIORITY] END) AS Spec
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SKILL_ASSOCIATION] AS SA
    ON SA.USER_PK = u.USER_PK
INNER JOIN SKILL_TYPE AS ST
    ON ST.SKILL_PK = SA.SKILL_PK
GROUP BY
    u.[USER_NAME],
    u.[USER_ID];
```

Comment: My Goodness that was fast! That is exactly what I'm looking for thank you so much! I will mark Accepted once the timer runs out.